# Automatically close MsgBox in vbscript?

Tags: shell, vbscript, wsh

I am using VBScript to code some automation on excel. I have a `MsgBox()` within the code, and am looking for a way to close the pop-up window created by `MsgBox()` automatically without human intervention. Program execution would continue from there.

Comment: Did you change your name again Tukai? OMG! Well what you need can be done! ;) It's called a **`MSGBOX timer which gets triggered after being idle....`**

Comment: @bonCodigo But how to do that?

Comment: Here's a very similar question I answered yesterday http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14095982/side-step-application-msgbox-in-vba-excel/14096445#14096445

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My comment has provided you tips to search and find out feasible answers. However to save your time, here is some insights.

- This post shows how you may [manupulate MSGBOX in VB](http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/hooks/messageboxhooktimer.htm).
- Here is the best possible way anyone could think of in terms of VBA.

  1. Create a form
  2. Use it as a MSGBOX
  3. Add a timer
  4. Given an elapsed time (idle) close the form.

--

- Another method [Reference](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/general-excel-discussion-other-questions/143673-visual-basic-applications-msgbox-timer.html). This uses a `Pop-Up` box as the MSGBOX.

Code:

```
Sub Test1()
 Dim AckTime As Integer, InfoBox As Object

 Set InfoBox = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 AckTime = 3
 Select Case InfoBox.Popup("Click OK or do nothing within 3 seconds.", _
 AckTime, "This is your Message Box", 0)

 Case 1, -1
  Exit Sub
 End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: any other way to close pop-up window generated by `MsgBox`?

Comment: @Tukai do check on the updated I made on the answer. It seems to be pretty well for you since you are working on VBScript. Try that and comment please.

Comment: yes i m trying,but meanwhile could you say what `0` does here ?

Comment: Here is the [syntax](http://www.itgeared.com/articles/1038-creating-pop-up-message-using-windows/). Please read on.

Answer (score 6):

The pure VBScript solution is [the .PopUp method](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156593.aspx).

Comment: +1, definitely ideal. I've used this before from VBA for the same reason.

Comment: @Ekkehard you are gr8 as usual!!

Comment: @Ekkehard can I have some help here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087681/merger-concatenate-employee-rows-depending-on-their-managers?

Comment: To make this answer stand alone and be more complete, please edit it to contain a brief example right here too.