# How to condense PowerShell script to fit on a single line

Tags: windows, powershell

Quick question. I am trying to write the following PowerShell script, but I would like it to fit on a single line:

```
$app = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$wb1 = $app.Workbooks.Open("C:\xampp\upload_files\Launchpad.xlsm")
$app.Run("Refresh")
$wb1.Close($false)
$app.Quit()
```

The pseudo-code would look something like this:

```
$app = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application AND $wb1 = $app.Workbooks.Open AND "C:\xampp\upload_files\Launchpad.xlsm") AND $app.Run("Refresh") AND $wb1.Close($false) AND $app.Quit()
```

The reason I want to fit on a line is because I would like to insert the arguments directly in the 'arguments' box of Windows Task Scheduler. The reason for this is that for some reason scripts have been disabled (e.g. I cannot call a .ps1 file...)

I know this will still work, as I already have a "one liner" PS script running. What would the syntax look like??

Kind regards,
G.

Comment: "The reason for this is that for some reason scripts have been disabled" - Rather than try to work around this, find out if there is a valid reason for this decision (there likely isn't, or the reason isn't known, based on how you've worded this). If it wasn't a conscious decision made with valid reasons, get it reversed.

Comment: If by "scripts have been disabled" you mean the Powershell Execution policy is set to "Restricted", you can override that in the command line when you call Powershell.exe.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Powershell statements can be separated with semicolons:

```
$app = New-Object -COM 'Excel.Application'; $wb1 = $app.Workbooks.Open("..."); ...
```

The PowerShell executable takes a `-Command` parameter that allows you to specify a command string for execution in PowerShell:

```
powershell.exe -Command "stmnt1; stmnt2; ..."
```

To run this via Task Scheduler you'd put `powershell.exe` into the "program" field and `-Command "stmnt1; stmnt2; ..."` into the "arguments" field of the task.

However, as @alroc said: you should verify why script execution has been restricted. If it's just the default setting you can simply change it by running `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` or override it by adding `-ExecutionPolicy ByPass` to a PowerShell command line. However, if the setting is enforced by policy changing/bypassing the setting will fail, and you could get into quite some trouble for violating company policies.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply! Your syntax works when I input the script directly into powershell ... however it doesn't work when I put it in the 'arguments' box of the Windows Task Scheduler?

Comment: Update: I have inserted the following code `-Command "$app = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application; $wb1 = $app.Workbooks.Open("C:\xampp\upload_files\Launchpad.xlsm"); $app.Run("Refresh"); $wb1.Close($false); $app.Quit()"` into the arguments section and nothing seems to work. The code however works perfectly when I input it direcly into powershell.. Is this a policy issue? Or is there still an error with the syntax? Thank you all again.

Comment: @Noobster: Try running the command line `powershell.exe -Command "..."` from a regular command prompt (`CMD.exe`).

Comment: Thanks man -doing this enabled me to see what was going wrong. Forgot to escape the " with a '. This is the annoying aspect of programming that sometimes makes me want to give up and set up a farm.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that you might use if the script is not that easy to convert, but you are on Windows running at least PowerShell V5.
It converts the code into `Base64` and uses `PowerShell.exe` with the parameter `-encodedCommand` to pass the encodedCommand as string.

```
$command = Get-Content .\YourPowerShellFileContainingTheCode.ps1 -raw
# Get-Content may require "-encoding utf8" or other encodings depending on your file
$encodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($command))
Write-Output "Text for application:"
Write-Output "PowerShell.exe" ""
Write-Output "Text for argurments:"
Write-Output "-encodedCommand $encodedCommand"
```

It would look like this, but with a much larger command:

```
Text for application:
PowerShell.exe

Text for argurments:
-encodedCommand SABvACAASABvACAASABvACwAIABzAHQAYQBjAGsAbwB2AGUAcgBmAGwAbwB3AA==
```