# Modify Proxy settings not working by batch

Tags: batch-file, internet-explorer, command-line, proxy

I wrote a batch file to enable or disable the proxy in the internet settings. the problem is that the change happend and I can see that in the RegEdit. But nothing will be applied till I open the Internet Setting window and closing it without doing any action. It means, that a refresh command should be done to apply the change in the registery.

can anyone help how can I do that please?

this code is to **Enable** the proxy:

```
@echo Estado
    reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
    @echo Proxy activado y configurado
    echo.
    pause
```

This code is to **Disable** the proxy:

```
@echo Estado
    reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
    echo.
    @echo Proxy desactivado
    echo.
    pause
```

Thanx :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch File to disable internet options proxy server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18439373/batch-file-to-disable-internet-options-proxy-server)

Comment: To enable a proxy you need to also set an address,port - see the link of possible duplicate.