# Bat file to enable/disable proxy

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, registry

Using windows, I'd like to know if there is some way to change proxy configuration by modifying the Windows registry through command line.

As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18439373/batch-file-to-disable-internet-options-proxy-server), you can always do:

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

or

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

This does uncheck the proxy option (see image). However, it does not applies the changes in the system. In other words, you get the option to be checked/unchecked, but it won't be applied unless you don't enter manually in the dialog and press "Accept".

[image]

Does anyone know what command makes it work straightforward?

Comment: ElPiter, this site is where members help others to fix issues with their posted code. We aren't interactive search bots, performing searches and gathering your reference material for you; that's your  task. Please take the [tour] and learn [ask].

Comment: If you want to apply the changes, I'm pretty sure you have to actually restart the system as there is no easy way to have registry updates ping the programs they are tied to and 'update the system'. You can however, use the shutdown command programatically in your batch file right after you set the registry. This shouldn't require you to click Accept on a dialog to change the system itself since system changes are completely based on whats read off the registry but most reads only happen at startup time

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18439373/batch-file-to-disable-internet-options-proxy-server/44752679#44752679